# Data in text block is not showing as designed (as table)

Tags: table, omnistudio, vlocity, omniscript

Design:
[image]

Preview:
[image]

I have designed the data in a tabular format in text block of omniscript but in the preview section or real time it is showing as random texts. as like images.

Please provide a solution for this issue.

Thanks in advanced.